# Solving modular exponentiation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, totient-function

Calculate :  $(8^{2^{6^{4^{2^{5^{8^9}}}}}}) (\mod 10000)$
But, the problem is that $8$ and $10000$ are not co-prime.
Moreover, the goal is to use Euler's theorem (modified?) to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: since they are not coprime, what can you say about the powers of $2$ involved here? And then work with the powers of $5$ and combine results (this is related to the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but you don't need to know that actually to solve the problem).

Comment: I could use a better explanation. Thanks for the comment, but i need a bit more explanation.